# How to count how many vowels our String have?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, do-while

I'm new in Java and I'm trying to solve a challenge. I have to write some words and to compare which one is longer, and how many vowels the longer one have. Also if you write "end", writing of words to end and to print something else, in our case **You didn't wrote any word**.

**Output Example in Terminal (CMD):**

> Write a word, or write 'end' to end writing: test
>   Write a word, or write 'end' to end writing: tee
>   Write a word, or write 'end' to end writing: testing
>   Write a word, or write 'end' to end writing: end
>
> Word testing is longest and it have 2 vowels.

**Output Example if you don't write any word:**

> Write a word, or write 'end' to end writing:
>   Write a word, or write 'end' to end writing:
>   Write a word, or write 'end' to end writing: end
>
> You didn't wrote any word.

Program should be coded using `Scanner (Input)`, `Switch Case` and `Do While`. Strings should be compared using method `equalsIgnoreCase()`.

I tried many times, and what I did is only writing and deleting code.

**This is my code:**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class VowelFinder {

public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        String word = null;
        int num = 0;
        String max = null;
        final String SENTINEL = "end";

        System.out.println(" ");

        do {
            System.out.print("Write a word, or write `" + SENTINEL + "` to end writing: ");
            word = scan.nextLine();
            if(!word.equalsIgnoreCase(SENTINEL)) {

                int nr = countVowels(word);
                if (num <= nr) {
                    num = nr;
                    max = word;
                }
            }
        } while (!word.equalsIgnoreCase(SENTINEL));

        if (max != null) {
            System.out.println(" ");
            System.out.println("Word `" + max + "` is longest word, and countains " + num + " vowels.");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println(" ");
            System.out.println("You din't wrote any word !");
        }

}   


private static int countVowels(String word) {
    int counter = 0;
    int vowels = 0;

    while(counter < word.length()){
        char ch = word.charAt(counter++);


        switch (ch) {
            //Lower Case
            case 'a':
            case 'e':
            case 'i':
            case 'o':
            case 'u':
            case 'y':
            //Upper Case
            case 'A':
            case 'E':
            case 'I':
            case 'O':
            case 'U':
            case 'Y':
            vowels++;

            default:
            // do nothing
        }
    }
    return vowels;
}

}
```

**Problem is:**

When I do so in terminal (CMD)

> Write a word, or write 'end' to end writing:
>   Write a word, or write 'end' to end writing:
>   Write a word, or write 'end' to end writing: end

It prints me **Word ' ' is longest word, and countains 0 vowels.**, but it should print **You didn't wrote any word.**

Can someone help me ? Where I did wrong ?

It should print me **You didn't wrote any word** if I don't write any word.

I hope I was clear and you can help me. If I wasn't clear please ask me.

Thanks for your contribution.

Comment: @Jobin [This is why I put Y](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/explore/is-the-letter-y-a-vowel-or-a-consonant).

Comment: @Emi try  if (max != null && max!=" ")  {}

Comment: @ then you must try (string.equals(null) && string.equals("")))

Comment: @RohitS Yes, I tried but still not working. Netiher `&&` neither `||` works.

Comment: YOu can simply use max.length()>0 in simplest form if nothing works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made some changes and it worked for me...

```
if (max != null && !max.trim().isEmpty() && max.length()>0) {
            System.out.println(" ");
            System.out.println("Word `" + max + "` is longest word, and countains " + num + " vowels.");
        }
```

Comment: Also it's working only if I use `if (max.length() > 0)`

Comment: Yes it will just added to ensure that it wont escape any spaces..also suggested by other user...:D

Comment: if it solved your problem consider marking it as answer..

Comment: Ya, thanks, but can you please explain what this do. I mean other beginner users will gain more, I hope.

Comment: Sure let me try framing  :1) max!=null ensure your input is not a null string 2) max.trim() will remove any whitespaces in case you add spaces and press enter and the return is chained to isEmpty() function which return true/false 3) also the max.length() ensure the length of your string is not < 0 (which you can avoid if you use only first two condition)

Answer (score 2):

change the if condition to

`if (word != null && !"".equals(word.trim()) && !word.equalsIgnoreCase(SENTINEL))`

I added a `null` check and did a `trim` to remove the white spaces.

Answer (score 0):

You could check in `countVowels()` whether the current word is nothing.

```
private static int countVowels(String word) {
    int counter = 0;
    int vowels = 0;
    if(word.length() == 0){
        return  -1;
    }
    ...
}
```

The return value is less than 0 so `max` won't be replaced.